# SQL, Where Function to Pull Fields with a YES/No condition

Tags: mysql

I have a database that tracks clients and their assigned staff. One client can have many staff assigned to them, but only one Case Manager. Not all clients have a staff member designated as the case manager. The table thus looks like this:

```
Client    Case Manager?        Staff 
John 1          1              Don 1
John 1          0              Don 2 
John 1          0              Don 3
John 2          0              Don 1
John 2          0              Don 2
John 3          0              Don 1
John 3          0              Don 2
John 4          1              Don 5
```

So, John 1 is assigned to three staff, but only Don 1 is actually the case manager. John 2 is assigned to two staff, none of whom are the case manager. I would like to be able to run a report that lists all the clients, and their case managers. If a client doesn't have a case manager, I need it to return a NULL or similar feature.

I can easily set it up to use a WHERE function to show me clients that have case managers, but that strips out those without.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Client, t2.Staff AS CaseManagerName
FROM
  tablename t1 LEFT JOIN tablename t2
  ON t1.Client = t2.Client
     AND t2.casemanager = 1
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51d18/4).

Or if a client can have more than one case manager you could use GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT t1.Client, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.Staff) AS CaseManagerName
FROM
  tablename t1 LEFT JOIN tablename t2
  ON t1.Client = t2.Client
     AND t2.casemanager = 1
GROUP BY
  t1.Client
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above data is in a single table, then use count() and group by:

```
select client, count(casemanager) from table group by client
```